# how to find the dtmf tones - asterisk?

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

I am working with Ubuntu 9.10 and asterisk 1.8. I am working on invinting sip clients in a conference room. I know I have to write call files and put them in the outgoing foder for each client.

Here is a call file:

```
Channel: SIP/1002
MaxRetries: 2
RetryTime: 60
WaitTime: 30
Context: confnr
Extension: 1234         //THIS IS THE CONFERENCE ROOM
```

in `extensions.conf` i have:

```
[internal]

exten => confno,1,MeetMe(,Mpc)

[confnr]

exten => 1234,1,MeetMe(1234,vMAqd)
```

Now I have a problem. If there are multiple conference rooms in meetme.conf how can i know (how to set the dialplan) what is the room number that a sip client selected?
A sip client calls `confno@domain` and than selects a conference number. How can I know what is that conf number and how to add it in the call file? Need some advices.
THX APPRECIATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on all your question availible here:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MeetMe

Comment: i read that link. I didn't find anything about ending a call in x minutes

Comment: use dial via Local channel to limit call length. no, you can't force conference to be ended at X minutes. to do that use external scripting(expert level required) and asterisk AMI interface.